# using useEffect to grab data from context on page load

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, react-context

i need help figuring this out. I have a token which i store in a context `globalContext`. I want to fetch that token when the page loads and make a request with it. But seems to me that when i try to fetch it using `useEffect` hook with a `[]` dependency, and try to log it to console it shows an empty line logged like this

[image]

if i remove the dependency `[]` on the hook. it logs the same line for 3-4 seconds and later it starts logging the token as it should be. What do you think is the issue here?

`GlobalContext`

```js
const GlobalContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [globalState, setGlobalState] = useState({
    userType: "", //Organisation or Changemaker
    showModal: false,
    modalContent: "", //profile, editprofile, studentlisting, orglisting, createlisting
    access_token: "",
    isSigningUp: false,
  });

  const [profile, setProfile] = useState({});

  const updateGlobalState = (key, val) => {
    setGlobalState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [key]: val,
    }));
  };

  return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider
      value={{ globalState, updateGlobalState, profile, setProfile }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

`useEffect hook`

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    
    console.log(globalState.access_token);
  }, []);
```

Comment: Can you share the globalContext and useEffect code? It's not easy to understand what might be wrong without seeing the code.

Comment: @jacobedawson i've edited the post. please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `globalState.access_token` as a dependancy of your `useEffect` callback. Example:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(globalState.access_token);
}, [globalState.access_token])
```

Note this function will fire everytime the value of `globalState.access_token` changes.

Comment: Yes this works, but why does the first time it runs log an empty output.

Comment: @KautilyaKondragunta because the initial value for `access_token` is set to an empty string.

Comment: oh so it runs before the access_token is even set. got it. Thank you!